# Retrieving field data from a List of class objects

Tags: c#, list, collections, dictionary

I am ultimately trying to store Vertex data: x, y, z. I am comparing two different collection types to store the data: `List<T>` and `Dictionary<K,V>`. Both contain the same public class data. Note the differences; my list uses a constructor (I add to the list later) and my dict uses a method to ADD to the dict:

my LIST

```
class Node1: List<Node1>
{
    public int nid;
    public double x, y, z;
    public Node1() {}
    public Node1(string strLine)
    {
        nid = int.Parse(strLine.Substring(8, 8));
        x = double.Parse(strLine.Substring(24, 8));
        y = double.Parse(strLine.Substring(32, 8));
        z = double.Parse(strLine.Substring(40, 8));
    }
}
```

and there's this one... DICTIONARY

```
public struct loc
{
    public double x, y, z;
}
public class Node2: Dictionary<int,loc>
{
    public int nid;
    public void Add(string strLine)
    {
        // collect the dictionary KEY
        nid = int.Parse(strLine.Substring(8, 8));
        // collect the dictionary VALUE
        loc data;
        data.x = double.Parse(strLine.Substring(24, 8));
        data.y = double.Parse(strLine.Substring(32, 8));
        data.z = double.Parse(strLine.Substring(40, 8));
        this.Add(nid, data);
    }
}
```

In my main I read in a text file with the Vertex data and do the following (a lot has been removed):

```
var Nodes1 = new Node1();
var Nodes2 = new Node2();

string strLine;

Nodes1.Add(new Node1(strLine));
Nodes2.Add(strLine);
```

Both collections now contain the same data.

Now here comes the question. I am looking for a specific instance of the class with the int "nid" that equals 1001 and I want to find the value of the corresponding double "x". To clarify that somewhat (because I just confused myself), I can check to see if an instance that contains nid=1001 exists by doing the following:

```
// does the entry exist - LIST
bool here1 = Nodes1.Exists(var => var.nid == 1001);

// does the entry exist - DICTIONARY
bool here2 = Nodes2.ContainsKey(1001);
```

To get the double "x" from the object that contains nid=1001 (for the dict) I do:

```
double here3 = Nodes2[1001].x;
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the data from the List collection. Perhaps it is because the List collection was not intended for this purpose. But, if possible, how do I get the same out of the List?

Can someone also, perhaps, explain a another (better) way to do this? I still don't have a great understanding of WHY/WHEN to use the LIST and DICTIONARY collections as there seems to be 100 ways to do the same thing.

Comment: Well, if you want to get a value (i.e. vertex data) by its key, then a dictionary sounds like the better solution. I tend to use Lists when I'm interested in the position/sequence of the value. That said, are you sure you want Node1 inherit from List of itself?

Comment: @Corak. Apparently not. One of my attempts seemed to make an infinite loop of blank lists of itself, yikes. It does appear that using the Dict is a tidier way to go. And one more, there is probably an even better way to do this that I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: Usually you don't need to inherit from List or Dictionary. Just use these classes as they are. `Dictionary<int, loc> node = new Dictionary<int, loc>();` and then `node[1001] = someLoc;`

Comment: I considered using just a Dictionary. Why does that option exist then (Ex: public class Node2: Dictionary<int,loc>)? Is there a specific purpose for that outside just using a Dictionary on its own? The reason I used it is because my class Node2 has a lot of methods that I did not share. If I only used Dictionary and not a class then I would have many public static methods.

Comment: With inheriting from a class you're saying that the deriving class is basically the same as the parent class but with some extra functionality. So if your `Node` is basically a `Dictionary<int, loc>` with a little bit more, then there is nothing wrong with it. But why would you need a `public int nid` in a Dictionary? And why is the Dictionary responsible on how to interpret a string line? It seems like you want a bigger `class Loc` which has all the data of *one* line, knows how to read a line, maybe write it etc. and then use a Dictionary<int, Loc> to store objects of that class.

Comment: Your last suggestion is actually what I did to start with. And now that you laid it out like that it does seem more logical. The reason I changed was bc of the ease of creating instances and adding them to the dictionary like how I do above. I used public int nid so that I could see it while I was typing the code - to make sure it was doing what I thought was happening. Were you wondering why I didnt use a property instead of a field or why I didn't keep it private? I ask bc I'm not really sure when to use properties vs fields... or private vs public. At least not for what Im doing.

Comment: "the ease of creating instances and adding them to the dictionary" you see, these are (at least) two separate things which should be implemented in two separate functions. One function should only have *one functionality*. And equally there should be (at least) two classes, one (Loc) responsible for one set of data (a string line) and one (Dictionary) responsible for a collection of data that knows how to add/remove/etc. but does *not* know how to parse a string line to get a Loc.

Comment: You *could* write an `AddLine(string line)` to your derived Dictionary class, but that would pass the line to the Loc class to get a Loc object back and then work with that object. As for public/private fields: I don't see why one would ever need public fields. Properties give you much more flexibility. I even use private Properties for class wide "fields" most of the time, because  then I know wherever I need to work with it I have *one* point of access to the value and if I ever need to do "magic" with it I do it  there and it is the same for everywhere I use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        int index = Nodes1.FindIndex(var => var.nid == 1001);
        double here4 = Nodes1[index].x;
```

Comment: That answers both my questions. 1) how to do it, 2) that it requires more code to do this and that the Dict is cleaner code.